# How to add geofence on google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, geofencing, android-geofence

I have implemented this geofence from the google guide : https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

But, how do i implement this with google maps. What I want to do is turn on a google maps activity, and the user should touch the map at any point. And from that touch event It'll create a geofence (with a pre assigned radius) around that touch point. Then I need to query from my firebase database all the restaurant names in that geofence. I can't find any good guides on how to do this...I hope you guys can give me some insight/links/ or example code that can help me demonstrate this.

Cheers~